# Проблема с переменнами JS

Tags: javascript

Как сделать что бы при каждом нажатию на кнопку переменная увеличивалось

Answer (score 3):

```js
let count = 0;
$('button').click(function(){
 console.log(count++);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
```